# в чем разница Value value js

Tags: javascript

Пытался применить данную функцию но так и не понял почему ругается.
В чем разница Value и value.
Если писать свойство ( Value ) то все работает как надо, но если это свойство заменить в коде на ( value ) то не работает.
В чем причина они отличаются тока тем что одно написано с заглавной а другое нет
Почему не работает с если писать не с заглавной

```js
function viewdiv (id) {
// Сохронённое предыдущие значение hidden val
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("temp_div_id");
// Спрятать предыдущий hide old
if (hiddenVal.Value != undefined) {
   var oldDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenVal.Value);
   oldDiv.style.display = "none";
}
// Показать текущий show div
id.style.display = "block";
// Сохранить текущий save div ID
hiddenVal.Value = id.getAttribute("id");
}
```

```html
<img id="toggleLink" onclick="viewdiv(div_1)" src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png" width="64" height="64" align="top" data-tooltip=">>1<< Шея \ Амулет"/>

<img id="toggleLink" onclick="viewdiv(div_2)" src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png" width="64" height="64" align="top" data-tooltip=">>1<< Шея \ Амулет"/>

<img id="toggleLink" onclick="viewdiv(div_3)" src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png" width="64" height="64" align="top" data-tooltip=">>1<< Шея \ Амулет"/>


<div id="div_1" style="display:none"> >>> 1 <<< </div>
<div id="div_2" style="display:none"> >>> 2 <<< </div>
<div id="div_3" style="display:none"> >>> 3 <<< </div>

<!-- Сохронённое предыдущие значение hidden val -->
<input id="temp_div_id" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Как ругается? Какой результат вы ожидаете? Где в вашем коде `Value`? Больше подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: `Value` тут — это просто набор символов, все будет работать точно так же, если заменить его на `qweasdzxc`. А `value` — это свойство элемента, которое для Вашего input'а изначально равно пустой строке (а не `undefined`).